# Trying to produce stacked bar plots in ggplot using loops

Tags: r, ggplot2, nested-for-loop

## Introduction

Hello everyone. This is my first post here - I am trying my best to give you everything needed to be able to help me, hopefully I do not forget anything.

I am trying to build a loop that creates stacked bar plots using ggplots with loops but I fail because the loop variables to not get recognised in both ggplot labels and the 'group_by' command.

First, let me share you a part of my data frame:

## Data frame snippet

```
Germany <-
  structure(
    list(
      Weight = structure(
        c(
          0.9254366,
          0.9673721,
          1.1321498,
          2.7208848,
          0.7328256,
          0.9142997,
          1.53218,
          0.9577866,
          0.2420226,
          0.7830253,
          1.1321498,
          0.9828443,
          0.9770092,
          0.7830253,
          0.8787283
        ),
        label = "Weight",
        format.spss = "F10.7",
        display_width = 12L
      ),
      Q6 = structure(
        c(10L, 9L, 10L, 6L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 8L,
          7L, 9L, 10L, 7L, 10L, 10L),
        levels = c("1", "2", "3", "4",
                   "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "99"),
        labels = c(
          `1 - not at all important` = 1,
          `10 - absolutely important` = 10,
          `No answer` = 99
        ),
        label = "Q6: Support for Democracy - How important is it for you to live in a country that is governed democratically?",
        class = "factor"
      ),
      Q7 = structure(
        c(3L, 8L, 10L, 8L, 10L, 4L, 8L, 8L, 5L, 4L,
          10L, 10L, 9L, 2L, 9L),
        levels = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5",
                   "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "99"),
        labels = c(
          `1 - not at all democratic` = 1,
          `10 - completely democratic` = 10,
          `No answer` = 99
        ),
        label = "Q7: Support for Democracy - And how democratically is #COUNTRY_NAME being governed today?",
        class = "factor"
      ),
      Q8 = structure(
        c(4L, 9L, 9L, 7L, 10L, 4L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 2L,
          7L, 9L, 5L, 2L, 8L),
        levels = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5",
                   "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "99"),
        labels = c(
          `1 - not satisfied` = 1,
          `10 - very satisfied` = 10,
          `No answer` = 99
        ),
        label = "Q8: Support for Democracy - Overall, could you tell me how satisfied you are with the way democracy works in #COUNTRY_NAME?",
        class = "factor"
      ),
      Q9 = structure(
        c(2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L,
          2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L),
        levels = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "99"),
        labels = c(
          `Strongly agree` = 1,
          Agree = 2,
          Disagree = 3,
          `Strongly disagree` = 4,
          `No answer` = 99
        ),
        label = "Q9: Support for Democracy - To what extent do you agree or disagree with this statement?",
        class = "factor"
      ),
      D2_GENDER_BINARY = structure(
        c(2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L,
          2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L),
        levels = c("1", "2"),
        labels = c(Male = 1,
                   Female = 2),
        label = "Gender binary",
        class = "factor"
      ),
      D1a_AGEGROUPS_75 = structure(
        c(3L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 5L, 3L, 1L,
          5L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L),
        levels = c("18-29", "30-39",
                   "40-49", "50-65", "66-75"),
        labels = c(
          `Younger than 18` = 1,
          `18-29` = 2,
          `30-39` = 3,
          `40-49` = 4,
          `50-65` = 5,
          `66-75` = 6
        ),
        label = "Age Groups (max age 75)",
        class = "factor"
      ),
      Q5_14 = structure(
        c(1L, 6L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 2L,
          1L, 10L, 7L, 1L, 5L),
        levels = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5",
                   "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"),
        labels = c(
          `1 - not at all democratic` = 1,
          `10 - completely democratic` = 10,
          `No answer` = 99
        ),
        label = "Q5: Support for Democracy - The country’s security agencies collect data on their citizens’ internet activity : Countries around the world differ in how democratic they are. We sampled the following practices from around the world. How democratic do yo",
        class = "factor"
      ),
      Q14 = structure(
        c(39L, 9L, 7L, 6L, 8L, 9L, 8L, 11L, 7L, 11L,
          39L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 8L),
        levels = c(
          "1",
          "2",
          "3",
          "4",
          "5",
          "6",
          "7",
          "8",
          "9",
          "10",
          "11",
          "12",
          "13",
          "14",
          "15",
          "16",
          "17",
          "18",
          "19",
          "20",
          "21",
          "22",
          "23",
          "24",
          "25",
          "26",
          "27",
          "28",
          "29",
          "30",
          "31",
          "32",
          "33",
          "34",
          "35",
          "36",
          "37",
          "38",
          "96",
          "99"
        ),
        labels = c(
          Reform = 1,
          Centre = 2,
          EKRE = 3,
          SDE = 4,
          Isamaa = 5,
          `CDU/CSU` = 6,
          SPD = 7,
          `Bündnis 90/Die Grünen` = 8,
          AfD = 9,
          FDP = 10,
          `Die Linke` = 11,
          `United Right (Zjednoczona Prawica)` = 12,
          `Civic Coalition (Koalicja Obywatelska)` = 13,
          `The Left (Lewica)` = 14,
          `Polish Coalition (Koalicja Polska)` = 15,
          `Confederation (Konfederacja)` = 16,
          `SNS coalition` = 17,
          `SPS-JS-KP-ZS` = 18,
          SPAS = 19,
          VMSZ = 20,
          `SPP-DPM` = 21,
          PSOE = 22,
          PP = 23,
          Vox = 24,
          Ciudadanos = 25,
          `Unidas Podemos` = 26,
          ERC = 27,
          Socialdemokraterna = 28,
          Moderaterna = 29,
          Sverigedemokraterna = 30,
          Vänsterpartiet = 31,
          Centerpartiet = 32,
          `Miljöpartiet de Gröna` = 33,
          `Servant of the People (Sluha Narodu)` = 34,
          `Opposition Platform- for Life` = 35,
          Fatherland = 36,
          `European Solidarity` = 37,
          `Voice (Holos)` = 38,
          Other = 96,
          `No answer` = 99
        ),
        label = "Q14: Which party did you vote in the #DATE1 parliamentary election? Please click on the answer option that applies to you",
        class = "factor"
      ),
      Q20 = structure(
        c(10L, 11L, 7L, 6L, 8L, 11L, 8L, 10L, 7L,
          9L, 40L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 8L),
        levels = c(
          "1",
          "2",
          "3",
          "4",
          "5",
          "6",
          "7",
          "8",
          "9",
          "10",
          "11",
          "12",
          "13",
          "14",
          "15",
          "16",
          "17",
          "18",
          "19",
          "20",
          "21",
          "22",
          "23",
          "24",
          "25",
          "26",
          "27",
          "28",
          "29",
          "30",
          "31",
          "32",
          "33",
          "34",
          "35",
          "36",
          "37",
          "38",
          "39",
          "97",
          "98",
          "99"
        ),
        labels = c(
          Reform = 1,
          Centre = 2,
          EKRE = 3,
          SDE = 4,
          Isamaa = 5,
          `CDU/CSU` = 6,
          SPD = 7,
          `Bündnis 90/Die Grünen` = 8,
          FDP = 9,
          `Die Linke` = 10,
          AfD = 11,
          PiS = 12,
          PO = 13,
          Polska2050 = 14,
          Lewica = 15,
          Konfederacja = 16,
          SNS = 17,
          SPS = 18,
          `Dosta je bilo` = 19,
          SSP = 20,
          Dveri = 21,
          `Demokratska Stranka` = 22,
          PSOE = 23,
          PP = 24,
          Vox = 25,
          Ciudadanos = 26,
          `Unidas Podemos` = 27,
          ERC = 28,
          Socialdemokraterna = 29,
          Moderaterna = 30,
          Sverigedemokraterna = 31,
          Vänsterpartiet = 32,
          Centerpartiet = 33,
          `Miljöpartiet de Gröna` = 34,
          `Servant of the People (Sluha Narodu)` = 35,
          `Opposition Platform- for Life` = 36,
          Fatherland = 37,
          `European Solidarity` = 38,
          `Voice (Holos)` = 39,
          Other = 97,
          `Would not vote` = 98,
          `No answer` = 99
        ),
        label = "Q20: Party Preferences - If there were a parliamentary election in the following days, which party would you vote for?",
        class = "factor"
      ),
      Q42 = structure(
        c(2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L,
          2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L),
        levels = c("1", "2"),
        labels = c(
          `Most people can be trusted` = 1,
          `Need to be very careful` = 2
        ),
        label = "Q42: Interest in Politics - Generally speaking, would you say that most people can be trusted or that you need to be very careful in dealing with people?",
        class = "factor"
      )
    ),
    row.names = c(NA,-15L),
    class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame")
  )
```

## Reproducible Working Example

When producing one single stacked bar plot, it works without any issues using the following code:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(sjlabelled)
library(surveytoolbox) # install with devtools::install_github("martinctc/surveytoolbox")
library(hrbrthemes)



# Define function to wrap long labels

wrap_label <- function(label, width) {
  str_wrap(label, width = width)
  
}

# Compute weighted counts by answer and age group

counts <- Germany %>%
  
  filter(!is.na(Q6)) %>%
  
  group_by(Q6, D1a_AGEGROUPS_75) %>%
  
  summarise(weighted_count = sum(Weight)) %>%
  
  ungroup()

# Compute weighted percentages by answer and age group and

# total number of observations and percentage for each answer option

total_obs <- sum(Germany$Weight)

percentages <- counts %>%
  
  group_by(Q6) %>%
  
  mutate(
    total_weight = sum(weighted_count),
    
    weighted_pct = weighted_count / total_weight * 100,
    
    total_weighted_pct = sum(weighted_count) / total_obs * 100
  ) %>%
  
  ungroup()



#   The plot itself

# Plot stacked bar chart with percentages

ggplot(percentages, aes(x = Q6, y = weighted_pct, fill = D1a_AGEGROUPS_75)) +
  
  geom_col() +
  
  scale_fill_brewer(name = var_labels("D1a_AGEGROUPS_75"), palette = "Set2") +
  
  # Add text labels with percentage for each age group on top of bars
  
  geom_text(
    aes(label = round(weighted_pct), group = D1a_AGEGROUPS_75),
    
    position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5),
    
    size = 3,
    color = "white"
  ) +
  
  # Add text label with percentage for each answer option above bars
  
  geom_text(aes(
    x = Q6,
    y = 100 + 2.5,
    
    label = paste0(round(total_weighted_pct), "%")
  ),
  
  size = 3) +
  
  labs(
    x = wrap_label(var_labels("Answer"), width = 60),
    
    y = "Weighted percentage",
    
    title = str_wrap(get_label(Germany$Q6)),
    
    subtitle = paste0("Germany (n=", round(total_obs), ")") ) +
  
  theme_minimal(base_size = 11) +
  
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1)) +
  
  guides(fill = guide_legend(title = str_wrap(
    get_label(Germany$D1a_AGEGROUPS_75, width = 65)
  )))
```

## Reproducible failing example

When trying to build my loop, I came up with the following code using a nested-for-loop. When I finally managed to get the code running through, the loop variable names in the ggplot labels and the by_group commands were being ignored and hence the plots do not look like the individually created one at all. I did read a lot about symlinks, strings and similar things and tried to adjust my code, but the code fails at the 'group_by' command.

Here is my current loop code. I hope you can help me finding out what is wrong with it. Please let me know if I can provide you with any additional information.

```
# Define variables to loop over
variables <- c("Q6", "Q7", "Q8", "Q9", "Q10_1", "Q10_2", "Q10_3",
               "Q10_4", "Q5_1", "Q5_2", "Q5_3", "Q5_4",
               "Q5_5", "Q5_6", "Q5_7", "Q5_8",
               "Q5_9", "Q5_10","Q5_11","Q5_12","Q5_13","Q5_14")

# Define grouping variables
grouping_vars <- c("D1a_AGEGROUPS_75",
                   "D2_GENDER_BINARY",
                   "Q14",
                   "Q20",
                   "Q42")



# Loop over variables and grouping variables
for(var in variables){
  for(group_var in grouping_vars){
    
    
    # Compute weighted counts by answer and age group
    counts <- Germany %>%
      filter(!is.na(var)) %>%
        group_by(var, group_var) %>% 
        summarise(weighted_count = sum(Weight)) %>% 
        ungroup()
    
    # Compute weighted percentages by answer and age group and  
    # total number of observations and percentage for each answer option
    total_obs <- sum(Germany$Weight)
    percentages <- counts %>%
      group_by(var) %>%
      mutate(total_weight = sum(weighted_count),
             weighted_pct = weighted_count / total_weight * 100,
             total_weighted_pct = sum(weighted_count)/total_obs*100) %>% 
      ungroup()

    
    # The plot itself 
    p <- ggplot(percentages, aes(x = var, y = weighted_pct, fill = group_var)) +
      geom_col() +
      scale_fill_brewer(name = var_labels(group_var), palette = "Set2") +

      # Add text labels with percentage for each age group on top of bars
      geom_text(aes(label = round(weighted_pct), group = group_var),
                position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5),
                size=3, color="white") +

      # Add text label with percentage for each answer option above bars
      geom_text(aes(x=var, y=100+2.5,
                    label=paste0(round(total_weighted_pct),"%")),
                size=3) +
      # Graphic titles
      labs(x = wrap_label(var_labels(Germany[[var]]), width=60),
           y="Weighted percentage",
           title=str_wrap(get_label(Germany[[var]])),
           subtitle=paste0("Germany (n=", round(total_obs), ")")) +
      theme_minimal(base_size=11) +
      theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle=45, hjust=1)) +
      guides(fill=guide_legend(title=str_wrap(get_label(Germany[[group_var]] ), width=65)))

    
# Save plot as png file with appropriate name based on variable and grouping variable names
ggsave(filename=paste0("Output/Plots/",
                           var, "_", group_var, ".png"),
           plot=p,
           dpi=300,
           height=4,
           width=7,
           units='in')
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that your loop counters `var` and `group_var` are character strings. And simply using these character strings in `dplyr` verbs or in `ggplot2` as if these are unquoted column names will not work. Instead you have to tell `dplyr` and/or `ggplot2` that these character strings are names of columns in your dataset which you could achieve by wrapping in the `.data` pronoun, i.e. use e.g. `.data[[var]]` instead of just `var`:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(stringr)
library(sjlabelled)

variables <- c(
  "Q6", "Q5_3"
)

grouping_vars <- c(
  "D1a_AGEGROUPS_75"
)

for (var in variables) {
  for (group_var in grouping_vars) {
    counts <- Germany %>%
      filter(!is.na(.data[[var]])) %>%
      group_by(.data[[var]], .data[[group_var]]) %>%
      summarise(weighted_count = sum(Weight)) %>%
      ungroup()

    total_obs <- sum(Germany$Weight)
    percentages <- counts %>%
      group_by(.data[[var]]) %>%
      mutate(
        total_weight = sum(weighted_count),
        weighted_pct = weighted_count / total_weight * 100,
        total_weighted_pct = sum(weighted_count) / total_obs * 100
      ) %>%
      ungroup()

    p <- ggplot(percentages, aes(x = .data[[var]], y = weighted_pct, fill = .data[[group_var]])) +
      geom_col() +
      scale_fill_brewer(name = var_labels(Germany[[group_var]]), palette = "Set2") +
      geom_text(aes(label = round(weighted_pct), group = .data[[group_var]]),
        position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5),
        size = 3, color = "white"
      ) +
      geom_text(
        aes(
          y = 100 + 2.5,
          label = paste0(round(total_weighted_pct), "%")
        ),
        size = 3
      ) +
      labs(
        x = wrap_label(var_labels(Germany[[var]]), width = 60),
        y = "Weighted percentage",
        title = str_wrap(get_label(Germany[[var]])),
        subtitle = paste0("Germany (n=", round(total_obs), ")")
      ) +
      theme_minimal(base_size = 11) +
      theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1))
    
    print(p)
  }
}
```

[image][image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer, this helped me tremendously! Just one small question. Like you, I get the value labels for the age groups. For other variables (like 'D2_GENDER_BINARY' for example), I cannot manage to get the value labels for male and female into the legend. When I check using 'attributes(Germany$D2_GENDER_BINARY), everything seems fine though. Do you have any clue why that might be?

Comment: Hm. I can not even guess. If you update your data to include a second grouping variable (and perhaps less of the response  variables (;) I will have a look.

Comment: Thank you for the offer. I just removed most main variable data from my data frame snippet. The other grouping variables are all still available in the failed code - namely "D1a_AGEGROUPS_75",   "D2_GENDER_BINARY",  "Q14",  "Q20" and "Q42".

Comment: I can only guess what went wrong when preparing your survey dataset. But the issue is that while e.g. your gender variable contains the labels as an attribute it's the levels what's used by ggplot2 for the labels. And the levels of the gender variable are 1 and 2 (in contrast to the age variable where the levels correspond to the labels). Hence, to fix your issue you have to recode the variables, using e.g. `Germany$D2_GENDER_BINARY <- factor(Germany$D2_GENDER_BINARY, levels = levels(Germany$D2_GENDER_BINARY), labels = names(attr(Germany$D2_GENDER_BINARY, "labels")))`